# Safe way to do ad-hoc class definition

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

### Background

I am currently working on a [library](https://github.com/Descent098/ezexcel) that allows the serialization of python instances to xlxs files. I am now looking to add deserialization, but instantly ran into a problem. Is there a safe way to create new class definitions in python without just using raw [exec()](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html?highlight=exec#exec)?

In this case I would want a load function that returns a list of instances of an ad-hoc generated class so that the deserialization state is the same as the serialized one, without the major security implications of just using exec. Does anyone have a reasonable solution.

### Current approach

```py
from copy import deepcopy

classes = [] # Stores all dynamically defined classes
instances = [] # Stores all dynamically defined instances

def _create_class(name:str, attributes:list):
    """Takes in a list of attributes to ad-hoc generate a class"""
    attributes = deepcopy(attributes) # Retain original attributes list
    attributes = '="", '.join(attributes) + '=""'
    execution_string = f"""classes.append(type('{name}', (object,), dict({attributes})))"""
    exec(execution_string)

def _create_instance(name:str, attributes:list, values:list):
    for current_class in classes:
        if current_class.__name__ == name:
            instance = current_class()
    assignment_string = ""
    for attribute, value in zip(attributes, values):
        assignment_string += f"instance.{attribute} = '{value}'\n"
    exec(assignment_string)
    instances.append(instance)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    attributes = ["name", "age", "email"]
    values = ["Kieran", "21", "this-is-not-my-email@example.com"]
    print(classes)
    _create_class("User", attributes) # Dynamically creates a new class called User with name, age, and email attributes
    print(classes)
    print(instances)
    print(_create_instance("User", attributes, values))
    print(instances)
```

This essentially dynamically generates:

```py
classes = []
instances = []

classes.append(type("User", (object,), dict(name="", age="", email=""))

instance = classes[0]() # In the above code this is found by checking each __name__ value on the classes

instance.name = "Kieran"
instance.age = "21"
instance.email = "this-is-not-my-email@example.com"

instances.append(instance)
```

I'm sure there is probably a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with two solutions, essentially all I cared about was having class access semantics. So in this case I can just instantiate a namedtuple, and not need a full class:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

def _create_namedtuple_class(name:str, attributes:list) -> namedtuple:
    return namedtuple(name, attributes)

def _create_namedtuple_instance(constructor:namedtuple, values:list) -> namedtuple:
    return constructor._make(values)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    attributes = ['name', 'age', 'email']
    values = ["Kieran", "21", "this-is-not-my-email@example.com"]

    User = _create_namedtuple_class("User", attributes)
    k = _create_namedtuple_instance(User, values)
    print(k.name) # Kieran
    print(k.age) #21
    print(k.email) # this-is-not-my-email@example.com
```

The other (worse for my use case) option is to generate a class using `type()` and then overwrite the **init** method to accept a dictionary that instantiates the class:

```py
def _safely_create_class(name:str, attributes:list) -> TypeVar("name"):
    def _init(self, **kwargs):
        for k,v in kwargs.items():
            self.__dict__[k] = v
    adict={key:"" for key in attributes}
    adict["__init__"] = _init
    return type(name, (object,), adict)

def _safely_create_instance(class_identifier:TypeVar("name"), attributes:list, values:list):
    kvdict = {k:v for k,v in zip(attributes, values)}    
    return class_identifier(**kvdict)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    attributes = ['name', 'age', 'email']
    values = ["Kieran", "21", "this-is-not-my-email@example.com"]

    # Safe version
    User = _safely_create_class("User", attributes)
    u1 = _safely_create_instance(User, attributes, values)

    print(u1.name) # 'Kieran'
    print(u1.age) # 21
    print(u1.email) # 'this-is-not-my-email@example.com'
```